# Magento 2.3 : Error while submitting the contact form

Tags: magento2.3, contact-form

When I try to submit the default contact us form, this is the error that I get.

> Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid range in
>   character class at offset 39 in
>   /home/hudsonpa/public_html/xxxxx/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/Classes/Emogrifier.php
>   on line 1507

Anybody knows what this is?

This is the form

```
<form class="form contact"
                  action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormAction()) ?>"
                  id="contact-form"
                  method="post"
```

On inspecting the final html, it points to

```
<form class="form contact" action="https://domain.com/xxxx/index.php/contact/index/post/" id="contact-form" method="post" style="float:unset; width:unset;" data-hasrequired="* Required Fields" novalidate="novalidate">
```

--- edit --- 
added screenshot
[image]

--- edit 2 ---

Also found the Emogrifier.php line 1507 has this

```
        $roughXpath = preg_replace(array_keys($this->xPathRules), $this->xPathRules, $trimmedLowercaseSelector);
```

and the **$xPathRules** array looks like this

```
private $xPathRules = [
        // attribute presence
        '/^\\[(\\w+|\\w+\\=[\'"]?\\w+[\'"]?)\\]/' => '*[@\\1]',
        // type and attribute exact value
        '/(\\w)\\[(\\w+)\\=[\'"]?([\\w\\s]+)[\'"]?\\]/' => '\\1[@\\2="\\3"]',
        // type and attribute value with ~ (one word within a whitespace-separated list of words)
        '/([\\w\\*]+)\\[(\\w+)[\\s]*\\~\\=[\\s]*[\'"]?([\\w-_\\/]+)[\'"]?\\]/'
        => '\\1[contains(concat(" ", @\\2, " "), concat(" ", "\\3", " "))]',
        // type and attribute value with | (either exact value match or prefix followed by a hyphen)
        '/([\\w\\*]+)\\[(\\w+)[\\s]*\\|\\=[\\s]*[\'"]?([\\w-_\\s\\/]+)[\'"]?\\]/'
        => '\\1[@\\2="\\3" or starts-with(@\\2, concat("\\3", "-"))]',
        // type and attribute value with ^ (prefix match)
        '/([\\w\\*]+)\\[(\\w+)[\\s]*\\^\\=[\\s]*[\'"]?([\\w-_\\/]+)[\'"]?\\]/' => '\\1[starts-with(@\\2, "\\3")]',
        // type and attribute value with * (substring match)
        '/([\\w\\*]+)\\[(\\w+)[\\s]*\\*\\=[\\s]*[\'"]?([\\w-_\\s\\/:;]+)[\'"]?\\]/' => '\\1[contains(@\\2, "\\3")]',
        // adjacent sibling
        '/\\s+\\+\\s+/' => '/following-sibling::*[1]/self::',
        // child
        '/\\s*>\\s*/' => '/',
        // descendant
        '/\\s+(?=.*[^\\]]{1}$)/' => '//',
        // type and :first-child
        '/([^\\/]+):first-child/i' => '*[1]/self::\\1',
        // type and :last-child
        '/([^\\/]+):last-child/i' => '*[last()]/self::\\1',

        // The following matcher will break things if it is placed before the adjacent matcher.
        // So one of the matchers matches either too much or not enough.
        // type and attribute value with $ (suffix match)
        '/([\\w\\*]+)\\[(\\w+)[\\s]*\\$\\=[\\s]*[\'"]?([\\w-_\\s\\/]+)[\'"]?\\]/'
        => '\\1[substring(@\\2, string-length(@\\2) - string-length("\\3") + 1) = "\\3"]',
    ];
```

When i individually take the patterns and compile them, there seems to be a problem in the third pattern (and a few others) at this spot

```
[\\w-_\\/]+
```

If I change it to

```
[\\w\\-_\\/]+
```

Then the pattern compiles.

Is this a good move?

Comment: can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @MohitRane, I added a screenshot. Thanks for stopping by,

Answer (score 0):

Checked out the Emogrifier code in its github repo.

https://github.com/MyIntervals/emogrifier/blob/master/src/Emogrifier.php

Refreshed my file with that code. All works fine now.